# How to display django form in modal window

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, django-forms, django-templates, bootstrap-modal

I have django form that must be show in a popup modal.
But when clicking on the link (`register`) that triger the modal containing the form, I got this (an empty fom):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVgVY.png)

As you can see, the form is empty. And the real form is displayed behind the empty one.

- Here is my modal.html: https://jsfiddle.net/aba2s/g3q20xsu/
- The index.html containing the link that triger my modal and the script that triger the modal(in the same page with button that triger the modal also):
  https://jsfiddle.net/aba2s/L5ta9e0b/